# autostart thunderbird on the tray in Lubuntu

Tags: thunderbird, lubuntu, autostart, systray

I want to have thunerbird minimized when I turn on the laptops.

when I do this: `vi /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` and added `@thunderbird` every time I turned it on a popup apear say that thunderbird is already running... but it works just fine.

- How do I clear that popup?
- how do I run it minimezed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add your startup application into `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` it will be run automatically twice - its just the way LXDE does stuff.

You can create an equivalent file and folder in your local home folder - this will autostart programs once.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu
nano autostart
```

add the text `thunderbird` into this file and save the file.

As to how to minimize the application on startup - this was recently discussed on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1529056)

In summary - install `wmctrl`

Create a script file called `~/start_thunderbird_hidden.sh`

Copy and paste the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

thunderbird &
while [[ $(wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird) == "" ]]; do sleep 0.1; done
wmctrl -r Thunderbird -b add,hidden
wmctrl -k on
```

Give this file execute rights:

```
chmod +x ~/start_thunderbird_hidden.sh
```

Then, instead of `thunderbird` in the autostart file above, use `/home/[youraccount]/start_thunderbird_hidder.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the procedure to autostart Thunderbird on Ubuntu 12.04 startup, put it in the tray as well as hide its icon from the launcher.

1. Open Thunerbird, Tools > addons > "get addons" tab > search for "mintrayr" and install "MinimizetoTray Revived" > restart TB
2. Tools > addons > "extension" tab > hit "preference" button of the newly installed MinTrayR extension > tick the 3rd choice "Instead of closing"
3. in a terminal `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` if not already installed
4. Create the file **/home/YourUsername/.start_thunderbird.sh**
5. Give it executable rights : Open a terminal and `chmod +x ~/start_thunderbird.sh`
6. Open the file and copy/past the following in it :

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   thunderbird &
   while [[ $(wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird) == "" ]]; do sleep 0.1; done
   wmctrl -c "Mozilla Thunderbird"
   ```

   it says to start Thunderbird, and to close it as soon as it's started...and the TB addon will take care to hide TB in the tray instead of closing it !
7. Right-top of your screen, Clic on start button > startup applications > add
8. Name it as you like, then browse for the file (or directly write in the box the path to your script : **/home/YourUsername/.start_thunderbird.sh**)

You're done ! Now you when you start Ubuntu, Thunderbird autostart and hide in the tray...